# Get posts by meta value except one post

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query, meta-value

I have a `meta_key` with name `director` in my posts and i tried to show all posts with some value like `christian bale` in director `meta_key`, i want to use this query in single.php and not showing Current post in new query

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can create common category for both of them and then assign to both .Check condition when displaying post that christan bell category is aasigned to movie posttype and then call that all movie posts that are in same category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the post for an actor for example, there is different solutions, but in my opinion, the best is to use `tag` as actors names, or `post meta`. The current solution I give to you is using WordPress search system and try to find posts.

```
// We try to get post for Christian bale as a keyword
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post__not_in'  => array(get_the_ID()), // We don't need the current post
    's'             => 'christian bale', // We put the Christian Bale search here
);

// Or as a meta value
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post__not_in'  => array(get_the_ID()), // We don't need the current post
    'meta_key'   => 'director',
    'meta_value' => 'christian bale',
);

$films = new WP_Query($args);

// If there's posts, show it
if($films->have_posts())
{
    while($films->have_posts())
    {
        $films->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();      
    }
}

// Reset query
wp_reset_query();
```

Using this after your post, or in your post will allow you to show post containing "christian bale" text.

Comment: how to use search in custom feilds ? example search in custom feilds {director} and how to search post title not just christian bale

Comment: If your custom field is a string, the best is to change the `$args`. I'll update my post.

Comment: Answer post is updated !

Comment: thanks for good answer how to change christian bale in 'meta_value' => 'christian bale', with post title ? i want used code in single php for all posts

Comment: `'meta_value' => 'christian bale',` will be `'meta_value' => get_the_title(),`

Comment: i tested this code not worked to me :(

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: example [p1 title: christian]  and [p2 title: christian bale] and ['meta_value' => 'christian',] so inside movie posts calling p1 and p2.  but i want just calling p1 and if meta_value = christian bale calling p2